Hyperlink inside LET formula works whilst when created as formula does not work
I have a question regarding the implementation of one formula.
I used the following formula for transforming a cell reference in a different sheet (eg.=Sheet1!A1) ,
= LAMBDA(selectedCell;
LET(
sheetName; MID(CELL("filename"; selectedCell); FIND("]"; CELL("filename"; selectedCell)) + 1; 255);
cellAddress; ADDRESS(ROW(selectedCell); COLUMN(selectedCell));
link; HYPERLINK("#'" & sheetName & "'!" & cellAddress; CELL("address"; selectedCell));
link
) )(Sheet1!A1)

and then creating a hyperlink with the reference. The problem lies when I transform this formula into a name defined formula in name manager (eg. LINKFORMULA(Sheet1!A1).
I tried to use the hyperlink and could not use it in the second instance, with the name defined formula.
Could you please help me with a solution.
Thanks.
